# Python Poplib Error

Tags: python, email, poplib

This is the code

```
import poplib
from email import parser

pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('user@gmail.com')
pop_conn.pass_('password')
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
for message in messages:
    print(message)
```

When it gets to the 8th line (`messages = ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]`)

It says this:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the bytes objects into string using [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```
messages = ["\n".join(m.decode() for m in mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
```

Comment: It still lists huge amounts of information how would I get this to list the just most recent message content

Comment: @JacobCorrigon, Change `1` from `range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)` so that it does not retrieve all messages.

Comment: @JacobCorrigon, For example, `1` -> `max(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) - 10 + 1)` to get at most 10 recent message.

Comment: Would that give me purely the contents of the message and nothing else?

Comment: @JacobCorrigon, It will retrieve most recent (or oldest, not sure) 10 emails.

Comment: It does that but still gives a wall of text how can this be shortened to just the text of the email eg. "How are you"

Comment: @JacobCorrigon, Please post as a separate question.